# Does not flushing a buffer lead to files having incorrect output

Tags: c++, c, buffer

In the code below, if I don't flush the buffer using `fflush(STDOUT)`, could it be that `FILE2` ends up getting both "Hello world 1" and "Hello world 2" since the buffer might be flushed at the end of the program and it might be holding both those statements by the end?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int FILE1 = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    int FILE2 = open("HelloWorld.txt",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,0666);


    dup2(FILE1,STDOUT_FILENO);
    printf("Hello World 1\n");

    //THE LINE OF CONCERN
    fflush(stdout);

    dup2(FILE2,STDOUT_FILENO);

    printf("Hello World 2\n");
    close(FILE2);
    close(FILE1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo that was a typo from my side, it was supposed to be `close(FILE1)` and `close(FILE2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you work on different levels here. The stdio-system and `stdout` will have its own buffer which will not be closed or flushed when you do the second `dup2` call. The contents of the `stdout` buffer will still remain and be written when `stdout` is closed at process termination.

So the `fflush` call is needed to actually flush the `stdout` buffer to the "file".

Comment: To reiterate, if we don't flush, we can end up getting both the statements on FILE2 right because they might be in the stdout buffer?

Comment: @FuturisticGladiator Yes that's correct.